# Help: Short film Credits (only 3 people)

Tags: terminology

I'm just finishing up my animated short and preparing to submit to film festivals but I'm unsure how to go about end credits. The visuals of the film (written, design, storyboards, animation, compositing editing etc.) was done by me. Then I employed a sound designer/composer who composed the music, did simple sfx, but also voiced the main character. Plus a musician for the music.
I know how to list the musician but unsure how to title myself and my sound guy.

Currently:

Written & Created by: me

Music & sound design
& voice of chara: sound guy

Flutist: musician

My sound guy's title seems clunky. I'm not sure "created by" is professional terminology.

So help and ideas?

Comment: Maybe ask the festivals to which you’re submitting if they have any requirements.  If they don’t, it’s probably completely a matter of taste.